# How to add a custom Thumbnail and a Title to a Link material in the assignment in a Google Classroom CourseWork

Tags: google-classroom

Is there a way to set custom Thumbnail and Title to a Link material for an assignment I'm sending from the backend?
I'm using Google PHP library:

```
$link = new Google_Service_Classroom_Link();
$link->setUrl('<the url here>');
$link->setTitle('<The title here does not appear>');
$link->setThumbnailUrl('<The thumb here does not work>');

$material = new Google_Service_Classroom_Material();
$material->setLink($link);

$courseWork = new Google_Service_Classroom_CourseWork();
$courseWork->setMaterials([$material]);
$googleServiceClassroom->courses_courseWork->create($courseId, $courseWork);
```

Even though the `Google_Service_Classroom_Link` object has those `set` methods, they just don't work and the link appears like that:
[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

[Kostiantyn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1875610/kostiantyn) There has been a feature request for this requirement-
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760273

Google has not provided any timelines for its implementation though. There is reference to a workaround which Google engineer seems to have suggested ( I have not tried that myself so not sure if it works). You can try that to circumvent the issue till Google comes up with a way to support it.